# Deactivate custom tool after getting map coordinates using QGIS Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am writing a custom tool to get printmap coordinates from the canvas.
The following code has been used to activate the map click on the canvas:

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolEmitPoint

class PrintClickedPoint(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)

    def canvasPressEvent( self, e ):
        point = self.toMapCoordinates(self.canvas.mouseLastXY())
        point = list(point)
        print point

canvas_clicked = PrintClickedPoint( iface.mapCanvas() )
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool( canvas_clicked )
```

Now I have called it in my code by :

```
canvas_clicked = PrintClickedPoint( self.iface.mapCanvas() )
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool( canvas_clicked )
```

It is working fine and I am getting the point, but now I need to deactivate this tool  and proceed with other code block written after that.
How do I do that?

Comment: Try this `iface.mapCanvas().unsetMapTool(canvas_clicked)`, see: https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#a900b4b4eaddefe0030a954a92335e391

Comment: Yes I have....but requirement is little different i want to unset the tool just after canvasPressEvent( self, e ): not before that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need overriding `canvasReleaseEvent`. Add it to the class definition.

```
def canvasReleaseEvent( self, e ):
    iface.mapCanvas().unsetMapTool( self )
```

After releasing the mouse button, the tool is deactivated.